# access control list not working on folders

Tags: linux, access-control-list

ive got a problem with setting up access control lists
for a folder that i want a single user to be able to edit, the permissions were set with the command

```
setfacl -R -m u:mik:rwx /srv/http/oshttpdocs/
```

and afterwards the output of getfacl is

```
# file: oshttpdocs/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::r-x
user:mik:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
```

this is the output of getfacl and yet the user mik cannot even read the directory from the terminal or the gui
if anyone has any ideas id be most grateful.

Comment: what is the permission/mode of /srv and /srv/http? can the user mik cd to /srv/http/oshttpdocs/?

Comment: no, cant access it at all for some reason, it can cd into /srv/ and /srv/http though and read everything inside them '# file: /srv/http
# owner: root
# group: root
user::r-x
group::r-x
other::r-x'

Comment: ah figured out the issue, it was being blocked by my selinux policy >.<

Comment: good. that makes sense.